# Android studio task bar was transparent

Tags: android-studio

I found that the task bar was moved to code area and be transparent.

I cannot find and option to move it back to the bottom.

I try to invalidate cache and restart android studio but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

View -> Status Bar solve the issue!

[image]